# How to add a list to a dictionary as a key value in python

Tags: python-3.6

I'm a new python learner and i have come here with a doubt

i have a dictionary my_dict with a 2 lists inside it with keys dic_keys and dic_values now i want to insert the popped elements from dic_values into dic_keys and also to create a new popped_ele key with all the popped elements as a list

```py
    my_dict = {'dic_keys':[],'dic_values':[1,2,3]}
    popped_ele = my_dict['dic_values'].pop()
    my_dict['dic_keys'].append(popped_ele)
    my_dict['dic_popped'] = [].append(popped_ele)
```

this is what i expected

my_dict
{'dic_keys': [3], 'dic_values': [1, 2], 'dic_popped': [3]}

but this is what i got
my_dict
{'dic_keys': [3], 'dic_values': [1, 2], 'dic_popped': None}

Comment: `list.append` returns `None`, so that's the value you are inserting to the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
my_dict = {'dic_keys': [], 'dic_values': [1, 2, 3]}
my_dict['dic_popped']=[]
popped_ele = my_dict['dic_values'].pop()
my_dict['dic_keys'].append(popped_ele)

my_dict['dic_popped'].append(popped_ele)
print(my_dict)
```